# How to get averages between different timestamps

Tags: mysql

I have a table with 3 Columns

```
ID | Teamid | Timestamp
```

we know that a round driven by participants is 2KM , each time they pass the control point a timestamp is added

Now we are searching to calculate for a selected team the averge speed between each timestamp so we can place it on a line chart.

```
ID  | Ploegnr| Tijdstamp

----------------------------------------

 1   |   1    | 2013-06-28 18:35:28

 2   |   1    | 2013-06-28 18:36:28

 3   |   2    | 2013-06-28 18:36:30

 4   |   3    | 2013-06-28 18:37:28

 5   |   2    | 2013-06-28 18:40:28

 6   |   1    | 2013-06-28 18:42:28

 8   |   3    | 2013-06-28 18:48:28
```

Have someone a idea or a clue how to start

this is another query wicht take the average from the latest 2 timestamp

i have already a query for the last 2 timestamps

```
SELECT a.*
 , 3600 / (UNIX_TIMESTAMP(a.Tijdstamp) - UNIX_TIMESTAMP(b.Tijdstamp)) * 2 snelheid 
FROM 
 ( SELECT x.*
    FROM Ronde x
    JOIN Ronde y
      ON y.Ploegnr = x.Ploegnr 
     AND y.Tijdstamp >= x.Tijdstamp
   GROUP
      BY x.ID
  HAVING COUNT(*) = 1
 ) a
 JOIN
 ( SELECT x.*
 , COUNT(*) rank
    FROM Ronde x
    JOIN Ronde y
      ON y.Ploegnr = x.Ploegnr 
     AND y.Tijdstamp >= x.Tijdstamp
   GROUP
      BY x.ID
  HAVING COUNT(*) = 2
 ) b
 ON b.Ploegnr = a.Ploegnr
 left join Ploeg as l on  l.id = b.ploegnr ;
```

Comment: Could you share the output you expect for this data so it's easier to understand your question?

Comment: You won't be able to do what you want with one query. With subqueries - may be....
May be it would be better to add a column names (lets say) 'delay' and calculate the delay every time timestamp is added? Having that column, you will be able to easily calculate average

Comment: I am not clear what you have in this table.  What is ID?  Is that the id of the timestamp?  And I take it from this data that two team members from team 1 did the first round(?), finishing at 18:35 and 18:36.  Is that right?  And what is the timestamp number 6?  Is that one of those same two team members finishing round 2 or a third member of team 1 finishing round 1?  This is way too unclear for us to help.  You must have other data (other tables) to work from.

Comment: what is the starting time then?

Comment: there is only one team with one unique id. A team with nr 1 , nr 2 and nr 3. Each time the pass the get a timestamp. So team 1 did the first round at 1 minutes because its 18:36 - 18:35. The second round they did it at 18:42 - 18:36 so 6 minutes